# mySQL average of all maximum value

Tags: mysql

I have table score like this.

[image]

Then I use query to get the maximum or highest average,

```
    SELECT stud_num, assess_type, MAX(average) FROM score 
    WHERE assess_type = "general" OR assess_type = "professional" 
    OR assess_type = "specialization"
    GROUP BY stud_num, assess_type;
```

Result is,

[image]

But I want to add every maximum value per ID and get the average. 
like student #1 = 70 +80 / 3, student #2 = 62.5 + 76 + 72 / 3 etc.
It is possible to do this in one query?

Desire output is

```
stud_num | average
1           50      //avg of general, prof, special
2           71.5
3           72.16
```

Comment: Why stud_num 1 should divide by 3 and not 2? or is it a typo?

Comment: nope because stud_num don't have general max value

Comment: so it should divide by the count of assess_type

Comment: I don't agree with your division by 3 for student number = 1 who only has 2 values for Prof and Special.  They have no value for General.  Or ALWAYS divide by 3 because the student SHOULD HAVE a value for the general category?

Comment: yes they should have to take the general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must solve your problem. Give it a try:

```
SELECT stud_num
     , (SUM(max_average)/3) as final_average
     , access_type 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT stud_num
            , access_type
            , MAX(average) as max_average 
         from score 
        where access_type IN ('general', 'professional', 'specialization') 
        GROUP 
           BY stud_name
            , access_type
      ) as temp_score 
  GROUP 
     BY stud_num
```

Comment: get rid of the top-level Access_Type field, not applicable since grouping by only the individual student.

Comment: wow this is great finally thx you very much this is correct and I get rid of the assess_type like Drapp said. I learn new thing. thx again

Comment: Well, glad that it helped you - I appreciate if you can vote it up too